# update-initramfs hangs on debian Stretch

Tags: debian, apt, initramfs, cpio

using *apt-get upgrade* on Debian left me with the decision to update to kernel 4.9.0-6 but the installation never finishes. It always stalls at the following stage:

```
Setting up linux-image-4.9.0-6-amd64 (4.9.82-1+deb9u3) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-6-amd64
```

Nothing happens after that. I do end the processes and start *update-initramfs -v -u* so see what happens and what not. The update-initramfs stalls at:

```
Building cpio /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-6-amd64.new initramfs
```

Does anyone have an idea what to do? The update from jessie to stretch (some days ago) went without any problems and I do not have modified anything since then.

Comment: if you do `sudo dpkg --purge os-prober`, is it able to complete?

Comment: Building the new initramfs file can take minutes. Find the PID of the `cpio` process under `update-initramfs` in the output of `ps af`, and run `strace -p <PID>` to see if it's chugging along. Also check your `kern.log` for disk errors.

Comment: I have the same problem: `Building cpio /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-1-amd64.new initramfs` hangs forever. I can't find any cpio process running on my system :o

Comment: Use `ps fux` to identify the process that hangs (the last process spawned during installation).

Answer (score 10):

thank you for all your answers. I solved the problem by using `ps faux` and identified that sync does nothing/waits forever.

As i had an usb drive which somehow died and got disconnected the drive still showed up as being mounted.

I renamed `/bin/sync` to `/bin/sync2`, copied `/bin/ls` to `/bin/sync` and ran `apt-get upgrade`. It was successful so I renamed the files, rebooted and finally got rid of the disconnected drive.

Comment: Thanks, I had this issue on Ubuntu while performing an `aptitude upgrade`, it hanged on *update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-133-generic*. I used `mv /bin/sync /bin/sync2 ; cp -a /bin/ls /bin/sync`, killed the */bin/sh /usr/sbin/update-initramfs -u* and re-ran `aptitude upgrade`.

Comment: +1 You just saved me fixing a database that runs nightly upgrades.